# How can I add image in list of itextpdf?

Tags: itext

this is my simple code below, I want to add a image to my list, but it doesn't work, and what i should do if I want add image with the String "item 2" have the same list, anybody has some advice? thanks so much!

```
Image image = Image.getInstance("xx.jpg");
    List unorderedList = new List(List.UNORDERED);
                unorderedList.add(new ListItem("Item 1"));
                unorderedList.add(new ListItem("Item 2"));
                unorderedList.add(image);
                document.add(unorderedList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it ! because class ListItem extens class Paragraph, so we can write

```
Paragraph a = new ListItem(); a.add(image); unorderedList.add(a);
```

Then the image can be added in List.